# Changue color depending on the factors in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
wine <-read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data",sep=",")

> head(wine,2)
  V1    V2   V3   V4   V5  V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12  V13
1  1 14.23 1.71 2.43 15.6 127 2.80 3.06 0.28 2.29 5.64 1.04 3.92
2  1 13.20 1.78 2.14 11.2 100 2.65 2.76 0.26 1.28 4.38 1.05 3.40
   V14
1 1065
2 1050
```

Which I am plotting like this:

```
plot(V2~V5, type="n")
with(wine, text(V5, V2, cex=0.6, labels=V1))
```

I want each factor of the labels that appear in the graphic to use a different color, how can I do it?

Comment: Try `plot(V2 ~ V5,  data=wine, cex=0.6, col=c("red","green","blue")[V1])` as a start

Answer (score 0):

We can try this

```
plot(V2 ~ V5, data=wine, cex=0.6, col=sample(colours(), 3)[V1])
```

[image]